# AngularJs (404) page redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, angular-ui-router

I am new to AngularJs and I have not yet managed to understand the ui-router. 
I am trying to redirect users to a 404 page when they access a wrong URL.

If I go to 'siteURL/app/home' the homepage is loaded, if I go to 'siteURL/app/wrongURL' I am redirected to a 404 page, but if I try to access 'siteURL/wrongURL' I get this error:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat
>   '/path_to_website_folder/node_modules/cloudcmd/wrongURL/'

instead of being redirected to the 404 page.

Also, if I try to access 'siteURL/app' I want to be redirected to 'siteURL/app/home'.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/app/404");
$stateProvider.state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    templateUrl: getPath('app.html')
})
.state('app.home', {
    url: "/home",
    templateUrl: getPath('app.home.html'),
    title: 'Home',
    keywords: "keywords",
    description: "description"
})
.state('app.404', {
        url: "/404",
        templateUrl: getPath('app.404.html'),
        title: '404'
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try add 
    `.state("otherwise", { url : '/404'...})`
if router didn't find any match with your states, it will redirect to otherwise state